# How can I spy on ngModel?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

**The problem**

I am unit testing a directive has no controller or template, only a `link` function. The directive requires `ngModel` and calls one of its functions in the `link` function. I want to spy on `ngModel` in my unit tests to ensure the right function is being called.

**The code**

Directive:

```
angular.module('some-module').directive('someDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attr, controller) {
      controller.doSomething();  //Calls some random function on the ngModel controller
    }
  };
});
```

**What I've tried**

I've tried to inject a spy `ngModel` like this:

```
beforeEach(module(function($provide) {
  $provide.factory('ngModelDirective', function() {
    return {};
  });
  $provide.factory('ngModelController', function() {
    return function() {};
  });
}));
```

As I discovered on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28840114/mocking-ngmodel-in-unit-tests), trying to override built-in properties causes an error to be thrown, and is bad practice.

So then I tried to test the directive the way the [Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing) say to:

```
var $scope = $rootScope.$new();
var element = $compile('<div some-directive></div>')($scope);
```

And spy on `NgModelController` like this:

```
var ngModelControllerSpyDoSomething = sinon.spy(element.controller('ngModel'), 'doSomething');
```

But this doesn't work, because one `$compile` is run, it executes the `link` function, so I'm not spying on it until it's too late (the spy is coming back as never having been called). This is also the case if I put `$scope.$digest();` before or after creating the spy.

Answer (score -1):

You will have to add your spy to the `$scope` you are injecting into the `$compile`-Function and then link it within the actual directive`s HTML`ngModel`, so:

```
var $scope = $rootScope.$new();
$scope.mySpy = // create a stub function with sinon here
var element = $compile('<div some-directive ng-model="mySpy"></div>')($scope);
```

Comment: How would I check whether a property of `ngModel` had been called, then?The function that's being called is a property of `ngModel`, it's not on the thing the model is linked to.