# Why does `controllerAs` in JavaScript work but not `ng-controller=...as...` in HTML?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

This works:

**[Plunker controllerAs in js](http://plnkr.co/edit/jJr649vljMyqqZx8P9Um?p=preview)**

input-form.html

```
<form name="inputForm" ng-submit="inputForm.$valid && inputCtrl.emitData()" novalidate>
  <textarea name="topic1Data" ng-model="inputCtrl.inputValues.topic1Data" rows="10" cols="30" required></textarea>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" ng-disabled="!inputForm.$valid">Compare</button>
</form>
```

inputForm.js

```
"use strict";

(function() {
  var inputForm = angular.module('input-form', []);

  inputForm.directive('inputForm', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'input-form.html',
      scope: {data: "="},
      controllerAs: 'inputCtrl',
      bindToController: true,
      controller: function() {
        var inputCtrl = this;
        inputCtrl.inputValues = {topic1Data: 123456789};

        inputCtrl.emitData = function() {
          inputCtrl.data =  inputCtrl.inputValues.topic1Data;
        };
      }
    };
  });
})();
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29558554/2848676

This doesn't work:

**[Plunker controller as in html](http://plnkr.co/edit/Rkc1ixSziWRp4I3iel27?p=preview)**

input-form.html

```
<form name="inputForm" ng-controller="InputController as inputCtrl" ng-submit="inputForm.$valid && inputCtrl.emitData()" novalidate>
  <textarea name="topic1Data" ng-model="inputCtrl.inputValues.topic1Data" rows="10" cols="30" required></textarea>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" ng-disabled="!inputForm.$valid">Compare</button>
</form>
```

inputForm.js

```
"use strict";

(function() {
  var inputForm = angular.module('input-form', []);

  inputForm.directive('inputForm', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'input-form.html',
      scope: {data: "="},
      bindToController: true
    };
  });

  inputForm.controller('InputController', function(){
    var inputCtrl = this;
    inputCtrl.inputValues = {topic1Data: 123456789};

    inputCtrl.emitData = function() {
      inputCtrl.data =  inputCtrl.inputValues.topic1Data;
    };
  });
})();
```

I found an [article by Pascal Precht](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2015/01/02/exploring-angular-1.3-bindToController.html) that seemed to say the solution was `bindToController` but I'm using `bindToController` and it doesn't work still.

How come the `controllerAs` in the JavaScript works but not the `ng-controller=...as...` in HTML?

Comment: From what I understand **bindToController** only works with **controllerAs** - https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#style-y076

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? I tried your plunkr, and it displays 123456789 in the textarea. What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead?

Comment: @JBNizet sorry I put the wrong Plunker link for the version that works.  I've corrected it in the question, but here it is for your convenience: http://plnkr.co/edit/jJr649vljMyqqZx8P9Um?p=preview. Expected behavior: given a number entered in the text area, when the user presses the compare button, then the number should appear as a label. It works with `controllerAs` in JS but not with `... as ...` in HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bindToController` works with a controller defined on the directive definition object:

```
.directive("foo", function(){
  return {
    //..
    bindToController: true,
    controller: "FooCtrl",
    controllerAs: "foo"
  };
});
```

In other words, when `$compile` service runs and compiles/links the directives, it collects the directives and binds to a `directive.controller` object. That is the controller that "binds" to the isolate scope properties.

In your case, you assumed (incorrectly) that a controller defined in the template with `ng-controller="FooCtrl as foo"` would work in the same manner. There is no basis for that assumption and the article that you linked to never showed that as an option.

The template can instantiate numerous controllers, not to mention that a template could be loaded asynchronously (with `templateUrl`), so the `bindToController` was never meant to be used in such a manner.

Comment: Thanks.  I seem to be missing some knowledge.  The two methods of creating controllers seemed equivalent.  What resource would you suggest I read to understand the differences between `controllerAs` syntax in JavaScript and `ng-controller=…as…` syntax in HTML?

Comment: @MichaelOsofsky, both act as an alias, in that they "publish" the controller function object on the scope under the `as alias` alias. But defining a controller on the directive definition object has other uses, like making it available via `require` or, for that matter, enabling the `bindToController`

Comment: I wonder if AngularJS should give an error if `bindToController` is specified without `controller`.

Comment: That error must have been introduced in a recent version because my version, AngularJS 1.3.15, does not report the error whereas your version, 1.4.0-rc.0, does.

Comment: One more gotcha I ran into applying this solution was [AngularJS "normalization"](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). I wanted to name the attribute `topic1Name` instead of `data`. I finally figured out I had to name the attribute `topic-1-name` in HTML and `topic1Name` in JavaScript. Similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29612749/angularjs-link-function-not-called-due-to-attribute-name-normalization