# Use ngModel on a custom directive with an embedded form, with working validation?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-model, angularjs-forms

I have a commonly reused set of form inputs that are reused throughout my application, so I am trying to encapsulate them in a custom directive. I want to set an `ngModel` on my directive and have that split up to be editable in several different inputs (some of them are directives themselves) within the main directive.

At the same time, I need the form validation results to be passed up the chain to a parent form so that I can display appropriate messages and styles.

**What is the simplest and most idiomatic way to implement this?**

These (simplified) templates should give you an example of what I'm going for...

### OuterTemplate.html

```
<form name="outerForm">
  <my-directive
    ng-model="ctrl.myComplexModel"
    name="myDirectiveInstance"
    custom-required="ctrl.EnableValidateOne"
    toggle-another-validation="ctrl.EnableValidateTwo">
  </my-directive>
  <div ng-messages="outerForm.myDirectiveInstance.$error">
    <ng-message when="customRequired">This is required.</ng-message>
    <ng-message when="anotherValidation">This is required.</ng-message>
    <ng-message when="innerValidationOne">Something wrong with field 1.</ng-message>
    <ng-message when="innerValidationTwo">Something wrong with field 2.</ng-message>
    <ng-message when="innerValidationThree">Something wrong with field 3.</ng-message>
    <!-- etc... -->
  </div>
</form>
```

### myDirectiveTemplate.html

```
<div ng-form="myDirectiveForm">
  <div ng-class="{'has-error': myDirectiveForm.fieldOne.$invalid}">
    <ui-select
      ng-model="model.fieldOne"
      name="fieldOne"
      required>
    </ui-select>
  </div>
  <div ng-class="{'has-error': myDirectiveForm.fieldTwo.$invalid}">
    <input
      type="number"
      ng-model="model.fieldTwo"
      name="fieldTwo"
      ng-pattern="directiveCtrl.someRegEx"
      ng-required="directiveCtrl.fieldTwoIsRequired">
  </div>
  <!-- etc... -->
</div>
```

At the moment, both `myDirectiveForm` and `myDirectiveInstance` are publishing themselves as properties of the `outerForm` `FormController`. I hoping to make this directive a black box, so the fact that `myDirectiveForm` is attaching directly to `outerForm` bothers me and seems to indicate that I'm doing something wrong.

Here's what my directive definition looks like right now.

### myDirective.js

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: 'myDirectiveTemplate.html',
    controller: 'MyDirectiveCtrl',
    scope: {
      model: '=ngModel',
      customRequired: '=?',
      toggleAnotherValidation: '=?'
    },
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, iElem, iAttrs, ngModelController) {

      // Black-box the internal validators

      // Custom validator to avoid conflicts with ngRequired
      ngModelController.$validators.customRequired = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
        if(!scope.customRequired)
          return true;

        // On first digest the field isn't registered on the form controller yet
        if(angular.isUndefined(scope.myDirectiveForm.fieldOne))
          return true;

        return !scope.myDirectiveForm.fieldOne.$error.required;
      };

      ngModelController.$validators.anotherValidation = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
        if(!scope.anotherValidation)
          return true;

        return scope.passesBusinessRule();
      };

      ngModelController.$validators.innerValidationOne = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
        if(!scope.anotherValidation)
          return true;

        if(angular.isUndefined(scope.myDirectiveForm.fieldTwo))
          return true;

        return !scope.myDirectiveForm.fieldTwo.$error.pattern;
      };

      /* etc... */

      // Deep-watching model so that validations will trigger on updates of properties
      scope.$watch('model', function() {
        ngModelController.$validate();
      }, true);
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked out a decent solution. In brief, I've removed the `NgModelController` implementation from my custom directive, and I'm relying entirely on the internal `FormController` from the `form` directive inside my custom directive. As far as I can tell, `NgModelController` just wasn't designed to *wrap* a form in a custom directive. However, nested forms are supported quite nicely in Angular, so this is the way to go.

Something I hadn't realized was that you can dynamically assign a name to a form as of Angular 1.3. While I can't prevent the "black box" from leaking up and attaching itself to a parent form controller, I can at least control the name it uses to publish itself in the parent scope, which is acceptable and is very similar to the API provided by `ngModel`.

Updated examples below.

### OuterTemplate.html

```
<form name="outerForm">
  <my-directive
    model="ctrl.myComplexModel"
    name="myDirectiveInstance"
    custom-required="ctrl.EnableValidateOne"
    toggle-another-validation="ctrl.EnableValidateTwo">
  </my-directive>
  <div>
    <span ng-if="outerForm.myDirectiveInstance.fieldOne.$error.required">Internal field 1 is required.</span>
    <span ng-if="outerForm.myDirectiveInstance.fieldTwo.$error.required">Internal field 2 is required.</span>
    <span ng-if="outerForm.myDirectiveInstance.fieldTwo.$error.pattern">Internal field 2 format error.</span>
    <!-- etc... -->
    <ng-messages for="outerForm.myDirectiveInstance.$error">
      <ng-message when="required">At least one required field is missing.</ng-message>
      <ng-message when="custom">
        Some directive-wide error set by validate-custom on outerForm.myDirectiveInstance.internalField
      </ng-message>
      <!-- etc... -->
    </ng-messages>
  </div>
</form>
```

In the outer template, I removed the `ng-model` directive in favor of a custom attribute. The `name` property may still be used to determine what name the internal form is published under.

Alternativately, the `ng-model` could be kept around, and an attribute `form-name` (with an appropriate alteration to the isolate scope binding below) could be used to publish the custom directive's `FormController` to the parent `FormController`, but this could be somewhat misleading since the `ng-model` directive isn't being used for anything except an isolate scope binding.

Either way, `ng-model` should not be used in conjunction with the `name` property for this use case. Otherwise, there may be conflicts as the `NgModelController` and the `FormController` attempt to publish themselves to the parent `FormController` (`outerForm`) under the same property name (`outerForm.myDirectiveInstance`).

Since validation errors bubble up to parent `form` directives, `ngMessages` may be used with this custom directive as shown. For more granular error handling, the internal fields of the directives can be accessed as well.

### myDirectiveTemplate.html

```
<div ng-form="{{ formName }}">
  <div ng-class="{'has-error': isInvalid('fieldOne')}">
    <ui-select
      ng-model="model.fieldOne"
      name="fieldOne"
      required>
    </ui-select>
  </div>
  <div ng-class="{'has-error': isInvalid('fieldTwo')}">
    <input
      type="number"
      ng-model="model.fieldTwo"
      name="fieldTwo"
      ng-pattern="directiveCtrl.someRegEx"
      ng-required="directiveCtrl.fieldTwoIsRequired">
  </div>
  <!-- etc... -->
  <input
    type="hidden"
    ng-model="someCalculatedValue"
    name="internalField"
    validate-custom>
</div>
```

The internal template of the directive stays mostly the same. The big difference is that the name for `ngForm` is now dynamically set.

To handle that with ngClass, angular expressions wouldn't work, so I updated my example to use a function on the `$scope` instead.

Last, for directive-wide business rules, I used a hidden input with an `ngModel` directive and a `name` set. I attached a custom mini-directive for validation to just this field. Validation errors on this field will bubble up to be used by the parent directive.

### myDirective.js

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: 'myDirectiveTemplate.html',
    controller: 'MyDirectiveCtrl',
    scope: {
      model: '=',
      customRequired: '=?',
      toggleAnotherValidation: '=?',
      formName: '@name'
    },
  };
});
```

Pretty much all the logic has been removed from the directive definition now.

Answer (score 0):

this is how I understand the directives. In this case both ng-model and myDirective are directives. It's not clear to me that if you are doing a

1) wrapper on ng-model OR
2) custom directive

Because if you want to do custom directive, you can just pass in the data, ex.

{ scope: { data: '=' }

And if you want to do a wrapper, you probably shouldn't pass in the other properties related to ngModel, which means you can still pass in the data

`ctrl.myComplexModel`, btw. model object can not be assigned to ng-model, because ng-model does not hold the object, it just holds the data.

NOTE: actually i found this post, [AngularJS - Create a directive that uses ng-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115701/angularjs-create-a-directive-that-uses-ng-model)

and apparently, you can pass in model, 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController

Anyway, it's just too complicated for me :) If you want to make a wrapper, the pattern seems to me

1. pass in the data
2. "has a" object

But apparently you might be doing "is a" object.

Comment: I'm trying to do a custom directive that implements the `ngModelController` api so that I can use Angular's native form validation (which relies on `ngModelController`) when using my custom directive inside a `form`.