# Change ng-model in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ngmodel

I want to create UI using custom directive.
I am doing it as :

Directive :

```
module.directive('testData', function() {
return {
    templateUrl: 'template/mainTemplate.html'
};
```

});

Template :

```
<form class="class">
<div ng-repeat='mainJson in mainJsonData'>
    <div class='mainJson.divClass'>
        <input type="{{mainJson.inputType}}" class="{{mainJson.inputClass}}" placeholder="{{mainJson.placeHolder}}" maxlength='{{mainJson.inputMaxLength}}' ng-model="mainJson.name"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

JSON data

```
[
{"divClass":"form-group","inputType":"text","inputClass":"form-control","inputNgModel":"name","inputMaxLength":"10","placeHolder":"Name"},
{"divClass":"form-group","inputType":"text","inputClass":"form-control","inputNgModel":"city","inputMaxLength":"10","placeHolder":"city"},
{"divClass":"form-group","inputType":"text","inputClass":"form-control","inputNgModel":"mobile","inputMaxLength":"10","placeHolder":"mobile"}
]
```

but in template ng-model is not working properly. It create UI as :

```
<input type="text" ng-model="mainJson.inputNgModel" maxlength="10" placeholder="Name" class="form-control">
```

Which is not correct. it should be like :

```
<input type="text" ng-model="name" maxlength="10" placeholder="Name" class="form-control">
```

Comment: Some Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115701/angularjs-create-a-directive-that-uses-ng-model

Comment: I am new in angular. I am getting same issue with ng-click also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this working [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/BRqJDZjwixtaaRguVwXd?p=preview) out

This is what you need :

```
<input ng-model="mainJson[mainJson.inputNgModel]" />
```

Just bind ng-model to the reference of object at property value `mainJson.inputNgModel` of array `mainJson`.

Point to understand here is that if you know the property of the array you want to access, you do it like this:

```
var getProperty = arr.thisPropertyIKnow;
```

If you want to get the name of property dynamically, do this:

```
var thisPropertyIDontKnow = 'valueAtRunTime';
var getProperty = arr[thisPropertyIDontKnow];
```

Complete template with illustration.

```
<form class="class">
  <p>Inside directive</p>

  <div ng-repeat='mainJson in mainJsonData'>
    <div class="{{mainJson.divClass}}">
      <input ng-model="mainJson[mainJson.inputNgModel]" type="{{mainJson.inputType}}" class="{{mainJson.inputClass}}" placeholder="{{mainJson.placeHolder}}" maxlength='{{mainJson.inputMaxLength}}' />
    </div>
    <p>value of ng-model is : {{mainJson.inputNgModel}}</p>
    <p>Dipplay the value inside the input field: {{mainJson[mainJson.inputNgModel]}}</p>
  </div>
</form>
```

Also, inside your directive, you need to initialize the array:

```
app.directive('testData', function() {
  return {
    templateUrl: 'mainTemplate.html',
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.mainJsonData = [{
        "divClass": "form-group",
        "inputType": "text",
        "inputClass": "form-control",
        "inputNgModel": "name",
        "inputMaxLength": "10",
        "placeHolder": "Name"
      }, {
        "divClass": "form-group",
        "inputType": "text",
        "inputClass": "form-control",
        "inputNgModel": "city",
        "inputMaxLength": "10",
        "placeHolder": "city"
      }, {
        "divClass": "form-group",
        "inputType": "text",
        "inputClass": "form-control",
        "inputNgModel": "mobile",
        "inputMaxLength": "10",
        "placeHolder": "mobile"
      }];
    }
  };
});
```