# angularjs - updating the `directive` collection from `ng-model`

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

How to update the `collection` in `directive`  while the `ng-model` updates in `template`?

here is my scenario: [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/btsvbZ7dglv9W0CvaO2p?p=preview)

my template :

```
var GridTemplate = [
            '<div>',
                '<div>',
                    '<ul class="titles"><li  ng-repeat="page in currentPage">{{page.title}}</li></ul>',
                    '<div class="rowContent">',
                    '<ul ng-repeat="(title,page) in currentPage">',
                        '<li  ng-repeat="element in page.key track by $index">',
                        '<input type="text" name="" id="" ng-model="element" ng-blur="numSort( page, element )" /></li></ul></div>',
                    '<div class="pageNavigator"><ul><li  ng-repeat="page in slides"><a ng-href="">{{$index+1}}</a></li></ul></div>',
                '</div>',
            '</div>'
            ];
```

my directive:

```
return {
        scope: {
            "pages" : "=",
            "viewports":"=",
            "numsorter":"&arrangeBy",
            "model" :"=ngModel"
        },

        template :GridTemplate.join(''),
        link: function(  scope, element, attrs  ) {

            scope.slides = [], scope.currentPageNo = 0;

            scope.numSort = function(  titleToSort, element ) {
                var requiredTitle = titleToSort ? titleToSort.title : scope.slides[0][0].title;
                scope.slides[scope.currentPageNo].forEach( function( item, index ){
                    if( item.title == requiredTitle ){
                        console.log( scope.model ); //not getting updated model
                        item.key= $filter('orderBy')( item.key, '', false ); //once the model updated requried to sort it again
                        $timeout(function(){
                            scope.$apply();
                        })
                    }
                })
            }



        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS - Create a directive that uses ng-model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115701/angularjs-create-a-directive-that-uses-ng-model)

Comment: For my case collections are supplied from directive

Comment: @RameshRajendran - can you help me to sort this issue? `http://plnkr.co/edit/btsvbZ7dglv9W0CvaO2p?p=preview` when i update something not reflects in array what i console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `ng-repeat` creates new child scope, so when you change item through `ng-model=value`, the new property inside scope is created. and not your actual array changed.

So change your binding to `ng-model=slice[$index]` to actually update the array.

See this working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zaSweNdBk9DEM0KMePrV?p=preview), I changed the input type to `number`, to reflect data as number., else it will update as string.

Another better approach would be to *`always have . in your model`* , which means you can create hierarchical scope object. like `slice=[{item:95},...{}..]`,

and then `ng-repeat='sl in slice track by $index'>"` 
and binding be like `ng-model="sl.item"`